# Change a date to the zone of another date

Tags: momentjs

I'm using `moment-timezone`.

I have a date with a timezone and another date without one. I want to convert the latter date to the timezone of the former. This works:

```
let otherDateInZone = moment.tz(otherDate, dateInZone._z.name);
```

But I'm nervous about calling `_z` because I guess the underscore means it's not part of the supported API.

What's the "correct" way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once an explicit time zone has been set, you can retrieve it with `.tz()`

```
let otherDateInZone = moment.tz(otherDate, dateInZone.tz());
```

The above will create a clone, leaving the original value of `otherDate` intact.  If you don't care about that, then you can just call `.tz(...)` on the existing object to mutate it.

```
otherDate.tz(dateInZone.tz());
```

Comment: I thought I tried everything. Everything except the most obvious tning. Thanks!